# Ruby on Rails - sum with to_f returning wrong value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
prices = ["1.6", "0.15", "1.8"]
prices.sum { |price| price.to_f }
```

But this returns `3.5500000000000003`, not `3.55`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Floating-point numbers cannot precisely represent all real numbers, and floating-point operations cannot precisely represent true arithmetic operations, this leads to many surprising situations.

I advise reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

You may want to use [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) to avoid such problems:

```
require 'bigdecimal'

prices = ["1.6", "0.15", "1.8"]
prices.sum { |price| BigDecimal(price) }
#=> 3.55
```

Comment: BigDecimal(nil) throws error.

Comment: Of course. Where is the `nil` coming from? In the array in your original question there is no `nil`.

Comment: `["1.6", "0.15", "1.8", nil].sum(&:to_r).to_f` seems to work with nil.

Comment: You can `require 'bigdecimal/util'` and use `["1.6", "0.15", "1.8", nil].sum(&:to_d)` instead which treats `nil` values as `0.0`, just like `to_f`.